# How to map Albers projection raster in Basemap of python?

Tags: python, gdal, coordinate-system, basemap

I confused the setting of Basemap about Alers projection. I want to plot a province area of Nation to pcolormesh. the value of lat_0 and lon_0 is Nation map's center longitude and latitude or this province map's center and origin lat?

```
driver=gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
driver.Register()
file0=r'I:\extract\temp\m2000041.tif'
ds=gdal.Open(file0,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
band=ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr=band.ReadAsArray()
gt=ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj=ds.GetProjection
xres = gt[1]
yres = gt[5]

# get the edge coordinates and add half the resolution 
# to go to center coordinates
xmin = gt[0] + xres * 0.5
xmax = gt[0] + (xres * ds.RasterXSize) - xres * 0.5
ymin = gt[3] + (yres * ds.RasterYSize) + yres * 0.5
ymax = gt[3] + yres * 0.5

ds = None
width = xmax - xmin + xres
height = ymax - ymin - yres


lllon, lllat, urlon, urlat = gt[0], ymin - 0.5 * yres, xmax + 0.5 * xres,  ymax - 0.5 * yres
xl, yl = np.arange(lllon,urlon,xres), np.arange(urlat,lllat,yres)

false_easting = 4000000                 #False easting
xm,ym = np.meshgrid(xl-false_easting,yl)
arr2 = arr
arr2[arr2==-32767]=0                 #exclude nodata value

fig = plt.figure()                 
plt.title("The Plot")
m = Basemap(width = width,height = height,projection = 'aea',lat_1 = 25,lat_2 = 47,lon_0 = 105,lat_0 = 0,resolution = 'c')  # set the Albers paraller lat1,lat2, central lon and lat origin of Nation map.
lonl,latl = m(xm,ym)

m.pcolormesh(lonl,latl, arr2)
plt.show()
```

This code output a blank plot. I doubt the coordiantion meshgrid is wrong.
How to plot the Albers map? Would you give a example?

Answer (score 2):

Given a projected raster written to a tif file, I use the following code snippet to plot it with `Basemap`. It uses `rasterio` to read the data and `pyproj` for coordinates transformations.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from pyproj import Proj

file = '/path/to/file.tif'

# Read the file data and metadata
with rasterio.open(file) as src:
    meta = src.meta
    data = src.read(1, masked=True)

# Extract shape/extent of the raster in its CRS
map_width = meta['width'] * meta['affine'][0]
map_height = meta['height'] * meta['affine'][0]
xmin = meta['affine'][2]
xmax = xmin + map_width
ymax = meta['affine'][5]
ymin = ymax - map_height
llproj = (xmin, ymin)
urproj = (xmax, ymax)
extent = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax] # [left, right, bottom, top]

# Instantiate projection class and compute longlat coordinates of
# the raster's ll and ur corners
crs = meta['crs']
p = Proj(**crs)
llll = p(*llproj, inverse=True)
urll = p(*urproj, inverse=True)

# Instantiate Basemap class
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=llll[0], llcrnrlat=llll[1], urcrnrlon=urll[0], urcrnrlat=urll[1],
            projection=crs['proj'],
            resolution='l', lat_0=crs['lat_0'], lon_0=crs['lon_0'])
            # There might be other parameters to set depending on your CRS


# draw coastlines.
m.drawcoastlines()
# PLot raster
m.imshow(data, origin='upper', extent = extent)
m.colorbar()
# draw parallels and meridians.
parallels = np.arange(0.,81,5.)
meridians = np.arange(10.,351.,5.)
# labels = [left,right,top,bottom]
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[True,False,False,False])
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[False,False,False,True])
plt.show()
plt.savefig('figure_name.png',dpi=100, transparent=True)
```

Comment: This is great. Very useful snippet!

Comment: i get a key error at crs['proj']. the crs object does not contain a key 'proj'